# Android Studio: Change location of .gradle directory

Tags: android, windows, gradle, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 0.52 with the default wrapper implementation. 
When I open a project Android Studio downloads the gradle 1.11 distribution files to {user.home}/.gradle directory. Unfortunately this folder is mapped to a network drive, that has only limited space.

I tried setting a global environment variable GRADLE_USER_HOME to a local drive, but that didn't work.
I also "installed" gradle locally and chose local installation in Android Studio's Gradle settings and set the Service directory path to a local drive. But it keeps downloading files to {user.home}/.gradle

Why does Android Studio ignore the Env Variable? Is there a way to change GRADLE_USER_HOME in Android Studio?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check content of gradle-wrapper.properties inside gradle folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug report http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2414 describing your problem. While the bug is fixed from Gradle's point of view you will only see it fixed when IDEA/Android Studio picks up newer version of Gradle Tooling API into their distribution.